# Parent object not accessing variables from children's script

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, artificial-intelligence, unityscript

I'm working on a project in Unity and I've created a script called DeerHater that targets the transform and controller of an object that enters the specified area. The script by itself works but it's connected to a parent object that has it's controller attached and that controller is supposed to access the variables of DeerHater and then do specified functions.

The problem is that the variables in controller doesn't change from empty to the variables that has changed in DeerHater since the desired object entered the trigger and it showups these two errors:

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

*MissingFieldException: DeerController.targetDeer*

I can't really see where the problem is since I'm a total beginner, could anyone tell me why wouldn't it acces DeerHater variables?

BearController script (parent object):

```js
var distanceDeer : float;
var deerHater : DeerHater;
var deer : GameObject = null;
var targetDeer : Transform;
var isFollowing : boolean = false;
var center : Transform;

var deerKilled : boolean = false;

function Start()
{
    deerHater = GameObject.Find("DeerHater").GetComponent(DeerHater);
}

function Update()
{
    deer = deerHater.deerController.
    targetDeer = deerHater.stupidDeer;
    distanceDeer = Vector3.Distance(deerHater.stupidDeer.position, transform.position);

if(deerHater.collisionDeer == true)
    {
        ChaseDeer();
        if(distanceDeer < attackRange)
        {
            deer.health = -0.1;
            deerKilled = true;
        }

        if(deerKilled == true)
        {
            GoBack();
            deerKilled = false;
        }
    }
}

function ChaseDeer()
{
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(deerHater.stupidDeer.position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    moveSpeed = 6;
    animation.Play("Run");
    animation["Run"].speed = 1.25;
    moveDirection = transform.forward;
    moveDirection *= moveSpeed;
    isFollowing = true;

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;    
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And here's the DeerHater script:

```js
#pragma strict

var stupidDeer : Transform;
var deerController : DeerController;

public var collisionDeer : boolean = false;

function OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Deer")
    {
        collisionDeer = true;
        stupidDeer = col.gameObject.transform;
        deerController = col.gameObject.GetComponent(DeerController);
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(col : Collider) 
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Deer")
    {
        collisionDeer = false;
        stupidDeer = null;
        deerController = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the line the NullReferenceException refers to, what variable is on that line? Something is `null`.

Comment: Yeah. It was in global variables and it wasn't set until the deer actually entered the trigger so the error kept spamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by placing DeerHater code inside the BeerController and moving the deer variables from global variables to if(deerCollision == true).